# Question regarding Google AppScript and updating information displayed for a third-party conferencing solution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to develop a Google Calendar add-on to integrate our software with Google Calendar, and am having trouble updating information once our software has been selected as a conferencing solution. Selecting our software from the conferencing solution dropdown correctly displays an Access Code, but I am trying to have this Access Code subsequently update after changing settings in the add-on menu. The AppScript documentation does not seem to have any information regarding updating already-created Conferencing Solutions, therefore I suspect the Conferencing Solution must be re-created when information to display changes.

Here is what my implementation for the entry point for our conferencing solution looks. I am trying to basically call "setAccessCode" again with a new access code.

[image: Code example]

Steps I have tried:

- Storing the original ConferenceDataService in storage and calling .setEntryPoint on it again with the new Access Code
- Calling the function defined in appscript.json for "onCreateFunction" for our conferencing solution again with the new data

Has anyone had any experience with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Conferencing is entirely new to me and haven't found any proper resource that shows its usage. Anyhow, what is your exact issue? Are there errors being returned? Or it just finishes without any issues but doesn't actually achieve what you want? I have found a postwhere it seems to be a [bug initially on ConferenceDataService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184503/cannot-create-conference-with-3rd-party-conference-solution-from-conference-solu/61363598#61363598). Try to provide an update here after seeing the post, comments and the answer below it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There do not appear to be any errors, as the our conference gets successfully added and appears correct with the initial Access Code. However, any attempts to change the Access Code that I have tried do not seem to update the Access Code displayed. I am basically just unsure on how to approach updating the Access Code of an already-created conferencing solution.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to try and reproduce your issue? Hopefully the actual code on the post, not just a screenshot.